# Ajax login and Laravel database sessions

Tags: php, ajax, session, laravel-4

I have been using the conventional way of signing in a user without ajax and since I have switched to ajax and a separate API, Authentication seems to work in itself, but the sessions are somehow not correctly set up ?

Here is the setup:

I have two Laravel projects, a web application for the front end and an API backend.
The user logs in via the front end laravel project which will (via ajax) make a call to the API which writes a new session into the database (yes, I use the database driver for the sessions and the two projects do use the same database). However, when I log in and take a look at the database, I see 8 new sessions or so, which is definitely not how it is supposed to be. What could be the cause for this ? FYI, I have checked and made sure that the ajax request is only executed once, not multiple times.
When I attempt to log the user in via Auth::attempt(), the authentication succeeds, but the user never seems to be logged in, which I suspect to be the sessions.

```
try {

  // attempt to log in the user with the given input
  if(\Auth::attempt(array('email'     => $input['email'], 
                           'password'  => $input['password'], 
                           'confirmed' => 1))){

        return \Response::json(["user" => \Auth::User()]);

    }
}catch(\Exception $e){
    return $e;
}
```

Here is the database table for the sessions:

[image]

#### EDIT

I tried to log in the user in the web app itself (not via the api project) calling `Auth::attempt()` and it works as expected, but I would like to log the user in via the Api (api and web apps share the sessions database), so I hope that information is somehow useful. On login via the web app, only one session is created, but on subsequent requests I get a lot more sessions. Is that normal ?

#### EDIT 2

The API actually is served from a subdomain (api.example.com) from a different project root. Could this be the issue (session cookies?)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using two different laravel setups for frontend and backend.

If yes then check your session name they might be created with same names for both frontend and backend. Change name of session of either frontend or backend.

Comment: Yes I do use different Laravel projects. I don't quite understand what you mean. When I authenticate the user on the API side, I want the Web App to know that the user is logged in. So the Web App should be aware of the session that was created on the API side, no ? How would a different name change that ?